# Fetch the row from html table on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So, I have a table with update button, and I want to be able to fetch a column from the row button was clicked on.

Below is the html code for table

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width: 99%">
        <thead class="thead-dark" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Trainee Class</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Trainees</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="nr">J001</td>
                <td>Java Stream</td>
                <td>01-April-2018</td>
                <td><button onclick="updateData()">Update</button>
                    <button>Remove</button></td>
                <td><button>View</button></td>
            </tr>
 <table>
```

So, when I click update, i want to fetch "J001" (first column of the update button row).

I tried below, but it's not fetching.

```
function updateData(){
     var $item = $(this).closest("tr")   
                 .find(".nr")    
                 .text();        

     alert($item);      
}
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass **this** in your update function call,

Your Html should be,

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width: 99%">
        <thead class="thead-dark" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Trainee Class</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Trainees</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="nr">J001</td>
                <td>Java Stream</td>
                <td>01-April-2018</td>
                <td><button onclick="updateData(this)">Update</button>
                    <button>Remove</button></td>
                <td><button>View</button></td>
            </tr>
 <table>
```

Jquery function should be,

```
function updateData(e){
     var $item = $(e).closest("tr")   
                 .find("td:first")    
                 .text(); 
     alert($item);      
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks @JeswinRebil